# cloud computing with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, cloud

I wanted to try cloud computing.

I went to [PythonInfo Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing) and found links to Google App Engine and PiCloud (which uses Amazon Web Services). However, it turns out that neither of them supports Python 3 (at least at first glance). I would hate to port my code back to Python 2.7.

Does anyone know if there's an easy way to use cloud computing in Python 3 (I don't care who the provider of computing power is)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With apologies for the self-promotion, my company are working on a cloud-based python environment.  We should be able to support all flavours of Python.  More info here:

http://www.pythonanywhere.com/